# Nodeos replaying from snapshot and what it means for the full transaction history

Tags: nodeos, chainbase

Let's say I have an application with the following transactions on chain with their respective blocks.

```
block 0 - <nothing>
block 1 - eat
block 2 - sleep
block 3 - play
block 4 - cook
```

And let't say I replay my `blocks.log` from snapshot at `block 3`

What does this mean for my chain state? Does this mean that If I query my chain table I cannot validate that `eat` and `sleep` happened since the chain was replayed after their respective blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain state is correct since every block is built on the previous block.

However, you don't have the transactions prior to block 3 so you can't figure out when/how the state was changed. But the state is ok.

Comment: Thank you so in theory I can still prove I "ate" and "slept" I just cannot point out at which point this happend/changed, or in other words  the "eat" and "sleep" will be in the state/db but not in the ledger?

Comment: Your example is not exactly clear about what you're doing with the values.

If you are inserting them into a table, then yes.  Your state table will have all 4 values, but you can't tell when the first two were done because you don't have the transaction history.

Comment: that's exactly what I meant thank you